# How to change the default rolling time in spdlog daily logger?

Tags: c++, logging, spdlog

Using [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog), how can I change the default rolling time of the daily logger?

In the following example, the rolling happens only at midnight:

```
auto logger = spd::daily_logger_st("my_logger", "fl_log.txt");
```

Comment: Look at sources. https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/master/include/spdlog/sinks/file_sinks.h there is no simple way, as I can see, but you can write your own think by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no direct way to change the rotation time in the daily logger - please open an issue [here](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues)..

A quick workaround would be to modify the `_calc_midnight_tp()` function to return the desired rotation time instead of midnight in the [daily_file_sink](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/master/include/spdlog/sinks/file_sinks.h) class..

For example to rotate in 1am instead of midnight:

```
static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point _calc_midnight_tp()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    time_t tnow = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
    tm date = spdlog::details::os::localtime(tnow);
    date.tm_min = date.tm_sec = 0;
    date.tm_hour = 1;
    auto rotate_time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&date));
    return system_clock::time_point(rotate_time + hours(24));
}
```

**Edit**: I [committed](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/commit/c401e830d043e33fee0a823d98810874cc385d85) a fix to this issue. Now user can set HH:MM of the desired rolling time